# I can't figure out this while and if problem

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

When I input my number or anything else, it just skips the if statement and goes to the else.  I can't figure out what's wrong; I've tried every way to change it. Still a total noob here.

```
arv = input("Sisestage arv: ")
    arv1 = 0
    kordus = 1
    
    
    while kordus <= 10:
        arv = input("Sisestage arv: ")
        if arv == arv.isnumeric():
             arv1 + arv
             print (arv1)
             kordus += 1
        else:
            print (arv)
            break
```

Comment: The line `arv1 + arv` does nothing useful.  Do you want to assign a value?  Increment a value?

Comment: `arv` is a string and `arv.isnumeric()` is a boolean, so they're never going to be equal.

Comment: Corrections: 1) change conditional to `if arv.isnumeric():`, and 2) change sum to `arv1 += int(arv)`

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to check if `arv == arv.isnumeric()`. `arv.numeric()` returns a boolean (True or False). To add a number to a variable you need `+=` not just `+`. Here is your fixed code:

```py
arv = input("Sisestage arv: ")
arv1 = 0
kordus = 1


while kordus <= 10:
  arv = input("Sisestage arv: ")
  if arv.isnumeric():
    arv1 += int(arv)
    print (arv1)
    kordus += 1
  else:
    print (arv)
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `isinstance()` function to check if the input is an int or not

```
arv1 = 0
kordus = 1

while kordus <= 10:
    arv = eval(input("Sisestage arv: "))
    if isinstance(arv, int):
        arv1 += arv
        print(arv1)
        kordus += 1
    else:
        print(arv)
        print(arv1)
        break
```